# Command line PDF reader

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, pdf, pdf-reader

Is there a command line program for linux that will let me read the text of PDFs?  I'll willing to live with a lack of pictures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several pdf2text tools in Ubuntu. For example, the [poppler-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/poppler-utils) package contains `/usr/bin/pdftotext`.

Answer (score 4):

[Howto Open a PDF file under Linux / FreeBSD](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-a-pdf-file-under-linuxfreebsd/) 
(lower part of article give you the options you are looking for)

Answer (score 3):

`pdf2txt.py` from the Python project [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

**zathura** is the tool you are looking for => http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/

For Ubuntu and Arch Linux, just use the package management tools `apt-get install zathura` or `pacman -S zathura` to install.

To view PDF in CLI/Terminals, just run `zathura /path/to`

**NOTE**: `zathura` depends on x11 client libraries, it cannot run without them. So if you ssh to a remote host and run `zathura` on it, you'll have to do X11 Forwarding (which means you need to run a X Server - Ubuntu Desktop will do).

Answer (score 1):

One can use `less PDFFILE.pdf`, which shows the text of the pdf. It requires `pdftotext` from `xpdf`. I think it works pretty well for pdf's with a lot of text.

Also if you want to be able to see the actual pdf  file (in low quality) you can use the [fbi](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/%20fbi), the linux framebuffer imageviewer.

```
sudo fbi PDFFILE.pdf
```

Small problem is that it needs root privileges.